# Having fun with Threads

Tags: android, multithreading

I am having troubles with Threading ;)

I have done an script about my class as follow:

```
class Test{
TextToSpeech mTts = new TextToSpeech();
boolean volatile mVarGlobal = false;

class T1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        doSomething(){
            mVarGlobal = false;
            // network working...Take a while
            mTts.speak(...) //Speech information received from Network
            mVarGlobal = true;
        }
    } 
    T1 t = new T1();
    t.start();

class CheckVarGlobal extends Thread{
    public void run(){  
        if(!mVarGlobal) {
            text2Speech.speak("something");
        }
    postAtTime(this, 3000);
    } 
}
CheckVarGlobal c = new CheckVarGlobal ();
c.start();
```

}

As you can see I have 2 Threads running, one which is getting network information and a second one which is cheking if the information from network has been received. The boolean variable mVarGlobal will be true, and then the Thread which is checking "CheckVarGlobal" will stop as the condition (!mVarGlobal) is false.

The problem is that once i get the information in the 1st Thread from network and speech the information, 2nd Thread still is running and speeching "something". I guess the 2nd Thread has not realize that CheckVarGlobal is true... I have typed the variable as volatile as it is used from 2 threads.

Any idea why is it happening, and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot,

Best.
David.

Comment: I have also tried using getters and setters synchronized with the variable mVarGlobal. But it doesnt still work :(

Comment: Why you're not using OnInitListener and OnUtteranceCompletedListener? Are you sure that: mVarGlobal = true; is invoked?

Comment: Using TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener?? Why should I?
I am using OnInitListender but it is independent of this part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dayerman... Here is some EXPERIMENTAL code with two handlers.

Edit. I have edited the code to comply with best practices, using a switch in a single handler:

```
private Handler myHandler= new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void  handleMessage(Message msg){          
            switch(msg.what){
                case 0:
                    if (!isDoneThinking){
                        editTextConfusedText.setText("Still Thinking "+new Integer(thinkSeconds).toString());
                        thinkSeconds++;
                        this.removeMessages(0);
                        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0),1000);
                    }
                    else {
                        thinkSeconds= 0; // reset timer
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    isDoneThinking= true;
                    onThreadedMessage(msg);
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    public void onThreadMessage(Message msg){
        Bundle b= msg.getData();
        String encryptedText="";
        if (b != null){
            encryptedText= b.getString("encryptedText");
        }
        editTextConfusedText.setText(encryptedText);
        Log.d(TAG,encryptedText);
    }
```

Usage:

```
buttonConfuseText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final String inString= editTextPlainText.getText().toString();
                    isDoneThinking= false;
                    myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0); // <=== START TIMER
                    Thread thread= new Thread( new Runnable() { // <== START THREADED RUNNABLE
                        public void run() {
                            String outString= encrypt(password,inString);
                            Message msg= myHandler.obtainMessage(1);
                            Bundle b= new Bundle();
                            b.putString("encryptedText",outString);
                            msg.setData(b);
                            myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                            Log.d(TAG,outString);
                        }
                    });
                    thread.setDaemon(true);
                    thread.start();
                }
            };
```

Comment: You should use wait and guarded blocks instead. Using sleep is inefficient as it has to wait a sleep cycle before the other thread can continue. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: I am wanting to be enlightened as to exactly where does the code call Thread.sleep? I _think_ the method sleep is just looping on delayed messages, providing a progress "bar" every one ms. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Hmm. Being practical I tested the code. I ran the timer code alone and the UI thread is not blocking. I ran the timer code and a timed runnable code together and the runnable code completes without blocking and the UI is not blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Your are checking the variable in if condition rather than while condition.That means whenever it comes to thread 2 that time only it is checking.Better to use while condition in thread2.

Comment: Hello ADIT, I think it doesnt matter if I use and IF, with the postAtTime method I do something similar to a while, but lees intrusive than a while loop. The problem is that mVarGlobal is not changing its value to true...